# How to make a Play-based web application reactive?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm new to Play, so bear with me. I'd like to understand the "reactiveness" of Play and how to best make use of it.

My web application needs to do the following:

- Receive an HTTP request (json format)
- Pass the request to a controller
- The controller needs to read a table (using Slick)
- The controller needs to populate a response (json format)
- The response is sent back to the browser

If I understand correctly, the application is Reactive when it uses asynchronous function calls to improve performance as a thread may be doing more that one thing at a specific time. But I don't see how the web application that I described can call a method and not wait for a response, there's nothing to do in parallel. What am I missing?

Comment: "there's nothing to do in parallel" -- How about handle 1000 other HTTP requests at the same time without blocking any threads?

Comment: That's exactly the point. What does the application need to do specifically so the application server supports multiple HTTP requests?

Comment: You can read the entire manifesto here: http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/ As you can see there are few more aspects than just "asynchronous". For example it talks about non-blocking: Let's assume you make a DB call and have an idle thread waiting for the response to arrive. That would be blocking.